# Developing $\exp z$ in a power series in $\pi i$

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

> > Develop $f(z)=\exp z$ in a power series in $\pi i$.

The task is fo find coefficients $a_n$ in such a way that
$$
f(z)=\exp z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (z-\pi i)^n.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
My idea is to develop $g(z):=f(z-\pi i)$ in a power series in $0$, because this power series does have the same coefficients $a_n$, because if (1), then
$$
g(z)=f(z-\pi i)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-\pi i)^n.~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
$$

Because one knows the exponential series, it is
$$
g(z)=f(z-\pi i)=\exp(z-\pi i)=-\exp z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(z-\pi i)^n\\\Leftrightarrow\exp z=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(z-\pi i)^n
$$
By comparing the coefficients in (1) and (2) it follows that the searched coefficients are
$$
a_n=-\frac{1}{n!}.
$$

It would be very kind of you if you gave me a short feedback whether this is okay.

With regards

math12

Answer (score 1):

Your result is right, but the way you explained it is muddled. Because the series expansion$$\exp z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!} z^n$$holds over the entire complex plane, it holds also under the replacement $z\leftarrow z-\mathrm i\pi.$ Hence$$-\exp z=\exp z\,\exp(-\mathrm i\pi)=\exp(z-\mathrm i\pi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!} (z-\mathrm i\pi)^n.$$So$$\exp z=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!} (z-\mathrm i\pi)^n.$$